# Rails error: `rescue in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

Earlier today I updated gems on my system with:

```
gem update
```

It updated few gems but after that I can't start my rails server, I get this error:

```
/Users/gugguson/rubys/my_rails_app/config/boot.rb:9:in `rescue in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
    from /Users/gugguson/rubys/my_rails_app/config/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

If I create a new app with:

```
rails new test99
```

... and then go into the folder and run rails server s I get this error:

```
[~/rubys/test99] rails s
<internal:gem_prelude>:168:in `load_full_rubygems_library': undefined local variable or method `path' for Gem::QuickLoader:Module (NameError)
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/setup.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/gugguson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/gugguson/rubys/test99/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Johann

Comment: I have tried to reload all bundles, removed bundler-1.0.10 to use previous version and restarted the computer, I have the same error.

Comment: What version of rubygems and ruby are you running. There were incompatibles between rubygems 1.5.x and ruby 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

As lebreeze said, try updating rubygems with `gem update --system`. Looks like there were [some issues](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1068) and that they were fixed in recent versions.